# Reset a tcolorbox option after setting it once using tcbset

Tags: tcolorbox, package-options

I'm using [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) package to draw colored boxes. After I set options with `\tcbset {opt1, opt2}` I would like to reset just the `opt1` back to default. After going through its [docs](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), I couldn't find a way to reset an option.

Here's what I want to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% set some option using tcbset
\tcbset { frame hidden, attach title to upper,coltitle=red, colframe=red }
\newtcolorbox[]{noframebox}[1][] { #1 }

% Following code resets everything back to package defaults
% I just want to make frame visible
\newtcolorbox[]{framedbox}[1][] { reset, #1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{noframebox}[title=No frame:~]
        So far so good.
    \end{noframebox}
    \begin{framedbox}[title=Framed:~] 
        % This must be in frame and title must be attached to frame.
        Every style option is reset for framedbox.
    \end{framedbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: Above code output]

Comment: Why don't you just add the options you want to your noframebox?

Comment: I have lot of options, so it results in a lot of code repetetion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tcolorbox` uses `pgfkeys` for its key=value interface. You can just define your own style inside that and reuse that style in different boxes. No code repetition (other than specifying the style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% set some option using tcbset
\tcbset{aravind/.style={attach title to upper,coltitle=red, colframe=red}}
\newtcolorbox[]{noframebox}[1][] {enhanced,frame hidden,aravind,#1}

% Following code resets everything back to package defaults
% I just want to make frame visible
\newtcolorbox[]{framedbox}[1][]{aravind,#1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{noframebox}[title=No frame:~]
        So far so good.
    \end{noframebox}
    \begin{framedbox}[title=Framed:~]
        % This must be in frame and title must be attached to frame.
        Every style option is reset for framedbox.
    \end{framedbox}
\end{document}
```

---

Another way, imho not as elegant, could be to manually set the `frame style` option to remove the effect of `frame hidden` (this could undo the effect from any other key altering `frame style` as well)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% set some option using tcbset
\tcbset { enhanced,frame hidden, attach title to upper,coltitle=red, colframe=red }
\newtcolorbox[]{noframebox}[1][] {#1}

% Following code resets everything back to package defaults
% I just want to make frame visible
\newtcolorbox[]{framedbox}[1][] {frame style={}, #1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{noframebox}[title=No frame:~]
        So far so good.
    \end{noframebox}
    \begin{framedbox}[title=Framed:~] 
        % This must be in frame and title must be attached to frame.
        Every style option is reset for framedbox.
    \end{framedbox}
\end{document}
```

---

Output of both code variants:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a question. If I had already added `frame hidden` option to `aravind/.style` then is there no way to reset just that key? This is useful in scenario where you have 9 boxes using frame hidden option and 1 box not using it. If I do your way I think I have to specify `frame hidden` for all the 9 boxes?

Comment: @AravindNujella or you define one style that contains every keys in common, one that uses the first style *plus* `frame hidden` and you're again good to go. There is no general way that I know of to reset only one specific key. However, in the special case of `frame hidden` it is possible to do something that undoes it.

Comment: @AravindNujella see my edit. Still I'd prefer using styles here.

Comment: That's cool. It solves my problem (avoiding the repetition) quite well. Thanks a lot!